# Why do i get run time error with the following code if do not check the empty root?

Tags: python

If I do not check (if not root), I will receive a runtime error. I try to do some research, but I do not know why. Can someone kindly explain what happens behind the scene?

run time error I receive:

> Runtime Error Message: Line 18: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'

```py
class TreeNode(object):
   def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
         self.val = val
         self.left = left
         self.right = right
def levelOrderBottom(self, root):
        if not root:
            return []
        que = []
        que.append(root)
        res = []
        while que:
            temp = []
            
            for i in range(len(que)):
                node = que.pop(0)
                temp.append(node.val)

                if node.left:
                    que.append(node.left)

                if node.right:
                    que.append(node.right)
            res.append(temp)
        return res[::-1]
```

Comment: What error are you seeing? Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: Runtime Error Message:
Line 18: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'

Comment: Please make sure that your code is formatted here *exactly* as it appears in your source file, since indentation matters in Python. And please show the entire *stack trace*, not just the error message.

Comment: Your nesting is messed up. If `root` is None it wont have a `val`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that `root = None` and read through your code. What will happen?

By the time the while loop starts, we'll have

```
que = [None]
res = []
```

Since `que` is not empty the while loop will get run. Since `len(que) == 1`, the for loop will also get run. In its first iteration, it will run `node = que.pop(0)`. Therefore

```
node = None
```

In the very next line, your code runs `temp.append(node.val)`. This is the cause of the error. There is no `val` attribute of `None`. Trying to call `node.val` when `node = None` causes an AttributeError to be raised.

Comment: you are genius. Thanks Alex